# SQL Server: How to avoid multiple updates to same row at high concurrency

Tags: sql-server, azure, concurrency, sql-update

Suppose I have an inventory blocking mechanism like below

```
update inventory.items 
set status = 'BLOCKED'
where id = (select top 1 id 
            from inventory.items 
            where status = 'AVAILABLE'
            order by id asc)
```

This code works well in most work loads. However, I am expecting a major increase in workload over next few days. Let's say 500 updates occurring per second coming from multiple web requests. I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 backend with Dapper providing the data access. The whole set up is in a single Azure Data center.

It's crucial for my business logic that the same row is not set to `BLOCKED` by more than 1 update. This will lead to more than 1 orders trying to block a single piece of inventory where the last one wins and others starve.

What is the best practice to adopt for such a scenario. Should I let SQL Server handle the load? Or is there a way to lock the selected item so that no one else gets to read it before the update happens.

Thanks a bunch for any help in advance!

Comment: You could add a `SERIALIZABLE` hint to the subquery: `FROM inventory.items WITH (SERIALIZABLE)`.

Comment: Better: lock the item for the duration of the transaction. Don't do the locking yourself. SS will always release the lock. Your code may block a record "forever" if something goes wrong.